# Render a Play!Framework2 javascript as template?

Tags: templates, playframework-2.1

I'd like to return a .js file from a template in Play!Framework 2.

Here's how I did that :

In my views folder, I created a template file :

```
initials.scala.js
```

Containinig something like :

```
{
    'data': @Model.find.findList()
}
```

And then, in my controller :

```
public static Result initials() {
    return ok(views.js.initials.render());
}
```

This is pretty straighforward for me, but I get this error :

> error: package views.js does not exist

What I did wrong?

If I rename js to txt (in the filename and the package call in the controller), everything works fine. But if I change it to js, I get an error.

Comment: it will be available soon https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/0b0b37dd095

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did nothing wrong, Play allows you tu use only `.html`, `.xml` or `.txt` extensions for views, so you need to use one of them.

From technical point of view it doesn't matter which one you'll use, anyway you need to return it from controller as JavaScript, ie with:

```
public static Result initials() {
    return ok(views.html.initials.render()).as("application/javascript");
}
```

Comment: That's sad, is there any reason why? I can understand for files like .exe, but for files like .js and .css that may contain variables it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by placing a route to the particular asset in your routes definition.

ie. GET   /assets/javascripts/initials.js     controllers..initials()

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `scala.js` file but you don't call it with `views.js.initials.render()` but instead `js.initials.render()`

At least with Scala it works with Play 2.2