# Generating Javascript from Play 2.2.0 framework - Java

Tags: java, javascript, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using Play! 2.2.0 for a developing a web application. I want to dynamically generate a Javascript from server side that can be included as a source in one of the HTML templates.

I have read everything about it on following links

- http://franzgranlund.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/play-framework-2-0-javascriptrouter-in-java/
- http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ScalaJavascriptRouting
- [Render a Play!Framework2 javascript as template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235446/render-a-playframework2-javascript-as-template)

Please find below the method that in my controller that is generating the Javascript template -

---> Application.java

```
public static Result getScriptForPage(){
   String generatedScript = "//Javascript code for the page//";
   return ok(views.html.scriptPage.render(generatedScript));
 }

public static Result javascriptRoutes(){
    response().setContentType("text/javascript");
    return ok(
            Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes",
                    routes.javascript.Application.getScriptForPage()
            )
    );
 }
```

--->routes

```
GET     /getScriptForPage        controllers.Application.getScriptForPage()

GET     /assets/javascripts/routes          controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

---> scriptPage.scala.html

```
@(generatedScript : String)
@generatedScript
```

I have another html page where I want to use this generated script. Something along the lines -

```
<script src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="UseGeneratedFileHere"></script>
```

OR

```
<script src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">UseGeneratedScriptHere</script>
```

Hitting /getScriptForPage shows the actual javascript i.e. "//Javascript code for the page//"

Further, is there a way to dynamically generate Javascript files under /assets from controllers that can be directly referenced from the html pages?

Comment: What is in the generated JavaScript? How do you generate it? Is it one for all?

Comment: As of now it is just simple string assignment e.g. var x =10;. But I intend to use dynamically generate from code.

I did find out that a similar solution can be found by passing generatedScript from the controller to the template. (moreScripts http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.2/JavaTemplateUseCases)

Is this the only solution?