# Play2.2 Java - Prevent escaping on Javascript template

Tags: javascript, json, playframework, playframework-2.2, scala-template

**Description:**

I'm trying to initialize a JSON object into my javascript template.

**View: views.tasks.task.js**

```
@()

@import play.libs.Json
@import enums.TaskType

...
var taskTypes = @Html(@Json.stringify(TaskType.valuesJson()));
```

**Model: TaskType**

```
public enum TaskType {

@EnumValue("General")
GENERAL(1, "General", "label-info", "item-blue");

...

public static JsonNode valuesJson() {
    ArrayNode arr = Json.newObject().arrayNode();
    for(TaskType tt: values()){
        arr.add(tt.jsonNode());
    }

    return arr;
}
```

**Result:**

```
taskTypes = [{\"value\":\"General\",\"label\":\"label-info\",\"itemColor\":\"item-blue\"}];
```

**Expected:**

```
taskTypes = [{"value":"General","label":"label-info","itemColor":"item-blue"}];
```

> **Question:** How to do it without escaping? Why is *@Html(...)* not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
    @JavaScript(Json.stringify(TaskType.valuesJson()));

**Explanation:**
Play use a JavaScript template format for files "*.js", so you need to use @JavaScript rather than @Html. It's clear after understanding how the templates engine works...

**Sources:**

- Helped to get there: [playframework JsValue in HTML Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309803/playframework-jsvalue-in-html-template)
- Helped to get there:
  [Render a Play!Framework2 javascript as template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235446/render-a-playframework2-javascript-as-template)
- There:   https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaCustomTemplateFormat
- There: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.JavaScriptFormat$